# Can I rule out a bad master cylinder if the pedal is firm with the engine off?

Tags: brakes, bleeding, master-cylinder

I am diagnosing excessive brake pedal travel (2 inches) and would like to rule out the master cylinder.

I remember one youtube video that said if the pedal has minimal travel with the engine off, one can rule out the MC.  Can anyone confirm if this is true?

---

Background

I recently changed calipers on my car.  Before the change, brake pedal travel was minimal.  I did not measure, but I’d guess the pedal moved half an inch before grabbing.

Now, the pedal moves 2 inches before stopping.

When the engine is off, a few pumps makes the pedal hard (0.25 inch of travel).
When the engine is on, the pedal travels 2 inches before stopping.

I’ve bled over a gallon of fluid and get no bubbles.  No obvious leaks in system.  I used a workaround to activate my ABS and bled afterwards.  I bled a fair amount of bubbles after the activation.  If I can rule out the MC, I’ll focus my attention on the ABS.
I don’t think the MC is the issue because it worked before the caliper change, but I want to rule out areas.